# How to convert JSON String to HashMap in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, hashmap, jwt

I am receiving a string like below (***Not in JSON or HashMap neither***) as kind of key value pair from implicit `JSONWebkey` crate:

```
{ "kid":"kid-value",
"kty":"RSA",
"use":"sig",
"n":"n-value",
"e":"e-value" }
```

Now how can I convert to proper `HashMap` to extract key and value of "e" and "n"? Or is there a simpler way to extract exact value of "e" and "n"?

Comment: Do you have the input as a json string? If so you can use serde_json, there is an example on their github if that is what you want. As for the jsonwebkey crate I am not familliar with it

Comment: "Not in JSON [...] JSONWebkey" that sounds a lot like JSON, why are you saying it's not? serde should be able to deserialise this to a hashmap just fine, or to a struct of the relevant fields.

Comment: No, JSON Web key generated from crate 'JsonWebKey_Convert' using '.to_jwk()' is returning string only, Please verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string *is JSON*, so you should just parse it. By default `serde_json` ignores all unknown fields, so declaring a struct with only the needed fields is enough:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Values {
    n: String,
    e: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let s = r#"{ "kid":"kid-value",
"kty":"RSA",
"use":"sig",
"n":"n-value",
"e":"e-value" }"#;

    let value = serde_json::from_str::<Values>(s)?;

    println!("{}", value.e);
    println!("{}", value.n);

    Ok(())
}
```